# javascript var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode;

Tags: javascript

how a code `var charCode = (evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode` could be explaned?
what happens here ?
all i understand is that clause returns buttons value to the object charCode.
but what those ? and : signs mean?
and can i use this thing in other languager? java/c++/php and so on?
Thanks

Comment: To add on to James answer, you will find this in many other programming languages. I'm fairly sure it's just used to make programmers feel superior. :D

Comment: This has to be a duplicate question, right?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It's called the [ternary conditional operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator). It's basically short for an `if...else`:

```
var charCode;
if(evt.which) {
    charCode = evt.which;
}
else {
    charCode = evt.keyCode;
}
```

Basically, it evaluates the first operand. If that evaluation returns `true`, the second operand is returned. If `false`, the third is returned.

As for whether you can use it in other languages, you often can. From the languages you listed, Java and PHP both have it, and I'd be very surprised if C++ didn't (edit - a quick Google reveals that C and C++ do indeed support it too). For more, see [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation).

Answer (score 2):

First, of all, `var charCode =` starts assignment to local `charCode` variable. Next, [ternary operator](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ternary_operation) is used. It compounds of three parts, condition, what happens if it's true and what happens if it's false.

```
(evt.which) ? evt.which : event.keyCode
# condition # if true   # if false
```

In this case, it's used for feature detection (keyboard key event). `evt.which` is proper way to do it, but in very old browsers you may want to use `event.keyCode`.

Comment: thank you! with the old browser explanation i finally got it haha

Answer (score 2):

Others correctly pointed out that it is shorthand for:

```
var charCode;
if(evt.which) {
    charCode = evt.which;
}
else {
    charCode = evt.keyCode;
}
```

but it is also longhand for:

```
var charCode = evt.which || evt.keyCode;
```

Answer (score 1):

This is called the conditional operator.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Conditional_Operator

To the left of the `?` is the condition. To the right are to results seperated by a `:`. If the condition is true, the result on the left of the colon is used, otherwise the it's the result on the right.

Comment: @zanlok, did you really suggesting linking to w3schools? I've updated the answer to a more credited site.